# Over the air update with React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Assume a scenario where I had published my app (which has been built with React Native) to Appstore/Playstore. Is it possible for me to stream new changes to the app without doing a new release (by this I mean a new version release).

Also if you guys came across any article related to React Native's app publishing process do share me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is one startup that is working on such product: [AppHub](https://apphub.io/)
Discussions about possible caveats you can find [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10048072)

If you want to build it yourself you can try to implement something [similar](https://medium.com/@clayallsopp/so-you-want-to-dynamically-update-your-react-native-app-d1d88bf11ede)

**Update:** There is free offering from Microsoft for Cordova and React Native projects - [CodePush](http://microsoft.github.io/code-push/)

Comment: I wonder if this violates App store guidelines  as it says "2.7 Apps that **download code** in any way or form will be rejected"

Comment: @NishanthShankar from AppHub FAQ: Does Apple permit this? - Yes! Section 3.3.2 of the iOS Developer Program explicitly permits this "provided that code does not change the primary or advertised purpose of the Application as submitted to the App Store."